# <ngb-pagination>: How to stop/undo a page selection?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm working on an Angular webapp where one of the pages has a table. The table shows part of a database depending on the "page" set at the bottom by . For example, page 1 shows rows 1-10, page 2 shows rows 11-20, etc. However, I am trying to make it so that if some data in the row is changed, it will stop the "page" change. @beforeunload is not going to work here since the page window remains unchanged, just the contents of it.

I tried messing around with pageChange, but it seems to be triggered once a new page is pressed, but the value is changed **after** the event is called. For example, let's say I did this:

HTML:

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]=totalItmes (pageChange)="changePageTest()" [(page)]="currentPage" [pageSize]="pageSize" [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
```

TS:

```
changePageTest(){
 let oldPage = this.currentPage;
 console.log(oldPage);
 this.currentPage = 3;
 console.log(this.currentPage);
}
```

And I selected "2" from the pagination:

[image]

The code would log "1", followed by "3", but then the button would show "2":
[image]

If I did the same thing with some other button, it'd log "2", followed by "3" again, but be that other button.

Is there some way to stop the button value from changing to what was selected, or to at least undo it? PageChange doesn't seem to work, since it does its stuff before the new button's value is set.